# MessageBox в EXT

Tags: javascript, html5, spring, extjs

Делаю проект с помощью EXT js. В частности `EXT.MessageBox.show(...)` открывает форму для ввода текста, далее она валидируется и, если не проходит валидацию, то должен вылететь алерт с предупреждением, а форма исчезнуть не должна. Потому такие вопросы:

- Как используя EXT открыть 2 messageBox одновременно, чтобы второй не задестроил первого?
- Как сделать MessageBox неубиваемым при нажатии клавиши "OK"?

Рассчитываю на вашу помощь и деятельные советы. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: 2 одновременно, либо же один за другим?

Comment: 2 одновременно.

Comment: 2 одновременно экст не умеет делать , только один за другим

Comment: Спасибо. Тогда такой вопрос: с помощью Ext.create('Ext.window.Window'....) Можно ли выполнить эту задачу? Задумка такая, чтоб сделать 2 итема, в одном формочка с вводом, в  другом предупреждение о неправильной валидации. По функции проверки, связанной с кнопкой поменять параметр visible у второй  формы. Можно и стоит ли так делеть?

Comment: лучше сделать валидацию "на ходу" и "светить" не валидные поля, в противном случае дизейблите кнопку инпута

Comment: Я имею в виду не валидацию vtype, мне подчёркивать в поле ввода текста ничего не надо. Просто введённый тест должен провериться в какой-нибудь функции. Если всё ОК, то окно EXt закрывается, если нет, то плюс к старому должно появиться ещё одно с предупреждением.

Comment: Ну в таком случае, без проблем, можно вываливать доп панель, и это позволяет делать месседж бокс

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, вызывать меседжбокс для предупреждения из функции, связанной с панелью?